# Why user32.dll mouse_event method doesn't perform mouse down event?

Tags: c#, click, user32, mousedown, mouseup

I'm setting up a simple C# application that sets window to foreground and performs clicks in a loop.

(I wrote the same program on windows 7 few years ago. Everything performed well that time.)
I am working on Windows 10 now.

```
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;

    public void DoMouseClick()
    {
        int X = Cursor.Position.X;
        int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }
```

Things seem to work except first part which is MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN.
If I hold down left button manually I can see the program releases it in the next step which is MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP.

How can I make mouse down performs as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) and use SetCursorPos(int x, int y) with x being Cursor.Position.X and y Cursor.Position.Y

```
int X = Cursor.Position.X;
int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
SetCursorPos(X, Y);

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Thread.Sleep(150);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 have bug, can't run `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` on some soft.